# UITableViewCell: Set UITextField delegate to nil in dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `UITableView` which cells contain one `UITextField` in it. My `UITableViewController` is a delegate of all this text fields. Now, when `UITableViewController` gets deallocated, I want to set delegate of all that text fields to nil. The text field has a tag, so I can get it by it's tag once I have a cell.

The question is how to get all created cells? Asking `UITableView` for `visibleCells` returns only visible cells, but it can happen, that there is a row which is not visible, bit it still has my `UIViewController` as a delegate. So I really need to get all created cells somehow. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` does the same, so it wouldn't work for me either.  The only way I see here is to store all text fields in array, but may be there is a better way?

Here is some code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseId"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"reuseId"];
        UITextField *nameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:nameTextFieldRect];
        nameTextField.tag = TEXT_FIELD_TAG;
        nameTextField.delegate = self;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:nameTextField];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    // todo: get all text fields and set theirs delegate to nil
}
```

---

Well, most answers suggest that I don't need to set delegate to nil, but as I'm paranoid, I suspect that the following scenario is possible:
User taps 'Back' button, so `dealloc` of my `view controller` is called. In `dealloc` my `view controller` releases it's table view, but the `tableView` still exists at this point, as well as all the text fields. And if somehow one of text fields would call it's delegate method at this point, the app would crash, because the delegate is not a valid object anymore.

If someone can explain why this scenario is not possible, than it would convince me that I don't need to set delegate to nil.

Comment: Did you create custom cell for tableview?

Comment: How about setting your `textField`s' delegates to nil, in `prepareForReuse`? That way, only visible cells will have their delegates set to the table view controller.

Comment: there is no need to do it, by default delegates have weak reference to cell, once `UITableViewController` is deallocated, all the cells also deallocated, and delegates are automatically set to nil

Comment: For your exact solution , i will give you the sample Code.Just use that.

Comment: @user3182143: no, I use just UITableViewCell.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer Well, it's possible that the cell is not visible and it has never been reused, so it still has a delegate.

Comment: No problem within a minutes i will give you the sample coding just use that.

Comment: Well, in that case, simply do these: (1)Override `willDisplayCell`, and set the textfields delegate there. (2) Override `didEndDisplayingCell` and set the text fields' delegate to `nil` over there. (3)In dealloc set the delegates of visible cells' fields.

Comment: For everyone who is harping on `weak` references, try this scenario in a MRC build (not ARC) and see what happens. OP might be ARC, I'm just saying for information sake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to do that. All of the cells will be deallocated as well, so they won't have a reference to the delegate.

By default the `delegate` is a weak reference, so it will not retain your object.

Comment: Please see addition to my question, where I explain why I can't accept it.

Comment: @Anastasia: Common sense is that if the delegate wasn't a weak reference, then the UITableViewController wouldn't get deallocated in the first place! When dealloc is called, there __cannot__ be either strong or weak references to the object. Even if Stefan Salatic's comment was wrong, there _still_ couldn't be a reference to the UITableViewController.

Comment: When you press back the deallocation chain starts. First the tableView will start deallocating which will deallocate all cells, then the tableView deallocation is completed, and only then is VC deallocated.

Comment: It works on a stack principle, so you do not have to worry about the refernces, since VC owns tableView and tableView owns cells.

Comment: Well, what I'm talking about is I'm afraid that view controller can receive message after the deallocation chain starts but before it ends. Are you saying it's impossible?

Comment: Yes it is impossible.

Comment: I disagree, just call `[self.delegate textFieldDidEndEditing:self]` in 'dealloc' of `UITextField` (assume we subclassed it) and app will crash. If I set delegate to nil, it wouldn't crash. You could say it's stupid to do this call in dealloc, but if I write a framework and I don't know how others will use it, I would prefer my class to be as safe as possible.

Comment: You might have some other strong references. I suggest you check with Xcode instruments as advised in other answer.

Comment: Also are you calling self after the super in dealloc? You should not do that. http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-init/

Comment: @StefanSalatic I use ARC, I don't need to call super in dealloc. I don't see what I can learn from Instruments here. self.delegate is a half-destroyed object, which is how it really is. What can I see in the Instruments?

Comment: @gnasher729 could you explain why "there still couldn't be a reference to the UITableViewController", because I do have reference to it, for example in one of my comments above I can ask text field for it's delegate and it's my view controller. And the delegate is weak, of course.

Comment: Sorry my bad about the super for ARC. But how do you think it would be possible for the delegate method to be called after the user has tapped back button? Since it's all done on the main thread, no input can be taken after that.

Comment: As for the instruments, you could see weak references as Zombies. They are the opposite of Memory leaks. So if you truly have a weak delegate pointing to non existing object, it would show.

Comment: For example, as in my comment with code above. I agree, the example is quite artificial, but it shows that it still possible to call delegate method after user tapped Back button.

Comment: Shouldn't your viewController be alive as long as the view is visible? But the time dealloc is called it shouldn't be possible to see textFields or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expecting to have this answer marked as accepted, but this won't fit into a comment window.

So, rather than us trying to convince you, you could start one of the most important tool for an iOS developer, which is the profiler. And see for yourself by playing with the interface that you should get no more than the number of cells necessary to fill the screen are kept allocated, and then when you tap back, all are getting deallocated.

If they are not, they probably have a strong reference to something else, but this can easily detected with the profiler.

I also like to add that when working with cells the act of scrolling UITable, tap back enter again into table, scroll tap back (repeated at least 10 times) it's a mandatory practice to detect memory leak.

Also, I don't know the purpose of assigning a tag to the cell, I maybe wrong but with this:

```
nameTextField.tag = TEXT_FIELD_TAG;
```

consider that you have more than one cell with the same tag, therefore you cannot simply recall the desired one. I remember that the rule is the first placed on screen 'win' the TAG (or kind of).

**[UPDATE]**

Just a guess, I have never proved this, but to stay on the question, if your problem is to have a cell first for having the UITextView, have you tried to loop the main view and just ignore the cell:

```
UITextView textView = [mainView viewWithTag:TEXT_FIELD_TAG];
while(textView!=nil){ // or whatever loop or criteria you like
   // deallo, nil, etc...
   textView = [mainView viewWithTag: TEXT_FIELD_TAG];
}
```

Comment: I assign tag to the text field inside the cell, so that I can access it later by `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TEXT_FIELD_TAG]`.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new delegate/protocol for that cell, and implement that delegate in the view controller, like PersonTableViewCellDelegate. Apart from that, your cell implements the UITextField delegate and in that code, call [self.delegate onKeyPressed] or whatever. I recommend you pass also a reference of the cell, so in the view controller you can use indexPathFromCell (or something like that) to know the position of the cell. If you are interested tell me about it and will copy some code.